# Preventing uninstallation of app in Android

Tags: android

I want to listen to an event of a particular app or package installed on Android emulator is about to uninstall. I want to show message to user before uninstall button is clicked. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. It shouldn't be possible at least, because it might cause malware to have abusive behaviour during uninstall.

Comment: but I want to just show message, user should be still able to uninstall app. Because my app is storing important user data, so if anybody tries to uninstall it, before starting of uninstallation my receiver should get intent or notification.